# Effect of natural environment on the development of cultures

Tags: cultural-history

Let there be this quantitative question: **how do the specifics of a natural environment influence the development of a newborn culture?**

Following are the specifics of the question:

- Which environmental factors are to be considered relevant here? Is it
  the *climate, temperature zone, humidity, weather characteristics,
  fertility of land, local ecosystems and animals, availability of
  resources, natural dangers and diseases*, etc.? Where in the cultural mosaic do these specific factors manifest themselves (one by one)?
- Can the natural environment be a decisive factor in the development
  of a culture? Take the (un)availability of basic resources (foods)
  for example: can this be a determining factor in developing into,
  say, a liberal or restrictive/hostile society? Etc. What other
  decisive factors could be considered here (if any) - and to which
  societal characteristics should they lead?
- To flesh out the explanation in all angles, do you have any
  qualitative examples that may be shown here? (as in significant environmental
  factors on cultures *in the classical mediterranean, in the viking
  society*, etc. ...)
- A bonus question (to be able to apply all that theory onto
  something): what could an underground society (lots of rocks and
  caves) develop into, culture-wise? (assuming that some limited
  amounts of sunlight and food sources are available). Note: *if this sub-question seems too vague (as in lacking some required data), feel free to use your imagination (to add that lacking data to the big picture by yourself).*

Comment: While the question is interesting, it's still one of those you could write a book about, what makes it not fitting this particular website. It's also not exactly history, rather anthropology. Speaking about particular examples of such influence would do, but talking about it in overall is a different matter.

Comment: @DarekWędrychowski: I can see you have a point; still, posting this question on the history subsite may be the closest match possible (i see no anthropology site here). Also, the particular examples, if diverse, may be good enough an answer, as applying some induction on the examples alone may get us at least close to the underlying rules.

Comment: Some elements are covered by Jared Diamond in his book, [Guns, Germs, and Steel](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Guns,_Germs,_and_Steel). I agree with @Darek that this question is too broad.

Comment: Hi. I've noticed you've also posted this on RPG.SE. You didn't really have to re-post it here, we can move questions between sites automatically. Next time, just flag the question for moderation attention and ask the moderators to migrate it to the more suitable site. It'll save you some time, and any answers and upvotes you got on the first site will follow the question (but not the downvotes, those are automatically removed when a question is moved ;).